# How to allow only one specific user to create products?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to allow only one specific user with a specific email/username to be able to create, read, delete and edit products for my ASP.NET MVC project.

I tried using `[Authorize(Users = "*specific name*")]` but it doesn't recognize users. Also if the fix is anything like this it needs to be in the controller class right?

The error I get is:

> The type or namespace 'Users' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What version of .NET are your targeting? The old [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute) had both `Roles` and `Users` properties but the newer [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute) only has `Roles`, so only supports role-based security at that level. Note that you can click on the attribute in your code and press F1 to go directly to the documentation for the one you're using.

Comment: I am using .net6. Any idea how I can make it so only one specific user with a specific username to have access to controller operations (CRUD)?

Comment: How about assigning a role only to that user and then allow only that role?

Comment: I tried with Role but it didn't work so I am trying to make it with a specific name

Comment: Sounds like you're missing some fundamental setup with your authorization. Please provide a [mre] to show what you've tried.